# How to use Stream in JAVA to get the object having a matching value?

Tags: java, java-8

I have two objects:

First object:

```
public class ABC {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private Boolean d;

    //getters and setters    
}
```

Second Object

```
public class DEF{

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    //getters and setters    
}
```

There are two Lists of objects ABC and DEF - List listabc and List listdef. And I want to run the following operation:

```
for(ABC abc : listabc){
  if (abc.getD()) {
    for(DEF def : listdef){
      if(abc.getA().equals(def.getA()){
        abc.setB(def.getB());
        abc.setC(def.getC())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am just looking to see if there's a way to implement this operation in Stream so that I can avoid iterating through lists and writing this code.

Comment: A Stream could be of only one type (class, interface). You could have objects of different classes in a stream only if they extend the same abstract class or implement a common interface.

Comment: "*so that I can avoid ... writing this code*" You have not avoided it, since it is already written. It works, and is easy to understand. Why not use it?

Comment: don't feel obligated to use fancy Java features when old school ones do the job properly ;)

Comment: Btw ... I suggest you to read a bit about Java code conventions. Classes like ABC and DEF, and single letter attribute names makes my eyes burn

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException The naming arguably does the job for this MWE, though.

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException -- I understand that :) This is just for an example here. Real objects in my code are different

Comment: @Michael -- I am just looking to make the code look simpler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should give the same output as your nested for loop.

```java
listabc.stream()
    .filter(ABC::getD)
    .forEach(abc -> listdef.stream()
        .filter(def -> def.getA().equals(abc.getA()))
        .findFirst().ifPresent(def -> {
            abc.setB(def.getB());
            abc.setC(def.getC());
        }));
```

Comment: thank you..it works... is there a good document I can follow on Streams

Comment: @gagan https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html is the official document for java stream API which written by Oracle. Early days I referred this document.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the 2 nested for loops with two streams:

```
List<ABC> listWithNewValues = listabc.stream().filter(ABC::getD)
            .map(abc -> {
                DEF matchingDef = listdef.stream().filter(def -> def.getA().equals(abc.getA())).findAny().get();
                abc.setB(matchingDef.getB());
                abc.setC(matchingDef.getC());
                return abc;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You use your 2 lists, listabc and listdef. You stream the listabc, you filter on the boolean and you map to the new values. During mapping you stream the listdef and find the matching element. You can extract the logic to a method to make it cleaner.

Comment: `findAny().get()` - You should not use `Optional::get` without checking it first. It can result in NoSuchElementException.

Comment: You can use ```findAny().orElse(null);``` to return null or  return a default object instead